# What is the effect of being prone in the Ubiquity RPG system?

Tags: movement, conditions, prone, defense, ubiquity

In the Ubiquity RPG system (used for Hollow Earth Expedition and other games), the action “Stand Up” reads:

> Falling down is easy; it is getting up that is hard. Your character can fall prone as a reflexive action, but standing up requires him to give up an attack action. Your character can move and defend normally after getting to his feet.

However, I cannot seem to find anywhere what the defence and movement implications of being prone are.

What are the effects on movement and defence (and other effects) of being prone in the Ubiquity system?

Answer (score 1):

There may be prone/crawling rules in other Ubiquity rulebooks, but there aren't any in Hollow Earth Expedition. I use the following house rules for prone/crawling:

- Going prone is a **reflexive action**
- A prone character's **Firearms** attacks gain a **+2 bonus** and **Melee**,
  **Brawl** or **Archery** attacks suffer a **-2 penalty**
- A prone character gains a **+2 bonus** to Defense against incoming
  **ranged** attacks and a **-2 penalty** to Defense against incoming **Melee** or **Brawl** attacks
- **Dodging** is not possible while prone, but **Blocking** and **Parrying** are
- A prone character gains a **+2 bonus** to **Stealth** rolls
- While prone, a character’s **Move** rating is halved, rounding down
- **Standing up** from prone requires an **action** or **move**, so a character may
  stand up from prone and attack or conduct another regular action, or
  they may stand up from prone and move a distance up to their Move
  rating, but not both